What would cause an AC multimeter reading to change if you reverse the probes?
I'm measuring the voltage in to a thermostat.
It's supposed to be AC.
When I measure wire1 and wire2 with black and red probes I get 0VAC
When I reverse the leads I get 1.8VAC
How can that even happen? It's alternating current.
Is there some waveform (squarewave, whatever) that could cause the AC reading to be "asymetrical"

If the voltage present is a combination of AC + DC the reading will depend upon how the meter is designed - they aren't all the same. What meter is it?
